# tc filter action tunnel_key unset to terminate a GENEVE UDP tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, tc

I want to terminate a GENEVE UDP tunnel coming from an AWS Gateway load balancer which is mirroring traffic. The idea is to decap the packet into its original form.

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 handle ffff: ingress
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent ffff: \
    flower \
    ip_proto udp dst_port 6081 \
    geneve_opts 0108:01:020000000000000000/FFFF:FF:FF0000000000000000,0108:02:020000000000000000/FFFF:FF:FF0000000000000000,0108:03:0100000000/FFFF:FF:FF00000000 \
    action tunnel_key unset
```

The problem I am having is that the decap doesn't seem to be happening. The below tcpdump captures the GENEVE header (UDP port 6081).

```
% sudo tcpdump -i any "udp port 6081 or udp port 4789" -nn

15:11:34.548567 IP 10.0.109.255.60202 > 10.0.40.230.6081: Geneve, Flags [none], vni 0x0, options [32 bytes]: IP 10.0.96.239.65428 > 10.0.102.143.4789: VXLAN, flags [I] (0x08), vni 14692826
IP 34.232.225.122.12321 > 10.0.96.239.8888: UDP, length 200
```

but what I would expect is the inner VXLAN header on port 4789:

```
IP 10.0.96.239.65428 > 10.0.102.143.4789: VXLAN, flags [I] (0x08), vni 14692826
IP 34.232.225.122.12321 > 10.0.96.239.8888: UDP, length 200
```

---

I am on kernel 4.14:

```
% uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-40-230.ec2.internal 4.14.311-233.529.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 23 09:54:12 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```